# Which WebApi OData namespace

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Which namespace should I be using for the latest Microsoft Web API OData:

System.Web.Http.Odata or System.Web.Odata?

The same classes appear in both namespaces, but I have not found anything directly stating which one to use.

I did find this article where the code examples are using System.Web.OData:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There exist two namespaces and assemblies because the two versions of OData are incompatible, though they can be used side-by-side.

Use `System.Web.Http.OData` for OData v3 and use `System.Web.OData` for OData v4.

You can read more about this on this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx

You can find samples for Web API OData v3 and OData v4 here: https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi

Comment: Useful answer and I really don't get why they didn't name the namespace by OData version, it would make life much easier

Comment: Updated blog post link: [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0/) and samples link: [https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples)